# How do you handle "mid-word pauses" during dialogues in novels?

Tags: creative-writing, dialogue, formatting

How do you handle "mid-word pauses" during dialogues in novels?

I rarely see it being done in novels, so I am not sure what are the various ways to format it. Could you tell me the most popular or widely used way to handle mid-word pauses in novels?

If I were to do it right now, I would do this:

> "America is the greatest. A-ME-RI-CA, I said, A-ME-RI-CA, not Eureka,
> that's not even a country."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sounding out the syllables and it's generally done in a way so that the sounds are properly enunciated.  Often this will keep the unstressed sounds lower case while the stressed sounds are all caps (a-MER-i-ca). Though it may also be properly capitalized (So A-mer-i-ca) especially in cases where it's generally understood by the reader what the proper pronuciation is.   Of course, there are alternate ways to achieve this.  Let's not forget the most famous instance of in dialog pronunciation in a novel:

> "It's leviOsa, not levioSA!"

Here we see that the stressed syllable is on the third syllable "le-vi-O-sa" not the fourth "le-vi-o-SA".